# Application error when trying to deploy heroku app

Tags: heroku, deployment

Deploying an app on heroku and the build succeeds but when I try to open it I get "application error" and it tells me to check the logs.

### The logs:

```
-----> Node.js app detected

-----> Creating runtime environment

       NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
       NODE_ENV=production
       NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
       NODE_VERBOSE=false

-----> Installing binaries
       engines.node (package.json):  unspecified
       engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)

       Resolving node version 12.x...
       Downloading and installing node 12.16.3...
       Using default npm version: 6.14.4

-----> Restoring cache
       Cached directories were not restored due to a change in version of node, npm, yarn or stack
       Module installation may take longer for this build

-----> Installing dependencies
       Installing node modules
       added 0 packages in 0.033s

-----> Build

-----> Caching build
       - node_modules (nothing to cache)

-----> Pruning devDependencies
       up to date in 0.219s
       found 0 vulnerabilities


-----> Build succeeded!
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types     -> (none)
       Default types for buildpack -> web
-----> Compressing...
       Done: 22.2M
-----> Launching...
       Released v6
       https://cbcv.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
```

---

Any ideas as to what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

Please provide the logs after the build is succeeded. You've given the logs while the app was being deployed. To view the recent logs you can use `heroku logs --tail`.